# Devolover varios tipos de datos LiveData

Tags: java, android, android-studio, programación-móvil

Como puede devolver varios tipos en LiveData
quiero retornar un String y Boolean

quiero cerrar un dialog y que retorne un mensaje

````
public MutableLiveData<String> deleteProduct(String id) {
    MutableLiveData<String> data = new MutableLiveData<>();

    database
        .collection(COLLECTION_PRODUCT)
        .document(id)
        .delete()
        .addOnSuccessListener(
            new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
              @Override
              public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {

                data.setValue("Producto Eliminado");
              }
            });

    return data;
  }```
````

Answer (score 0):

No se si te refieres a devolver al mismo tiempo un String y un Boolean o devolver uno u otro pero si es el primer caso puedes simplemente hacer que el tipo del LiveData sea un Map: `LiveData<Map<String, Boolean>>` y en tu setData creas el Map con ambos valores

Si lo que quieres es el segundo caso, devolver o un String o un Boolean entonces te recomiendo hacer una clase intermediaria:

```java
class Respuesta {
    @Nullable String mensaje;
    @Nullable boolean trueOFalse;
    Respuesta(@Nullable String mensaje, @Nullable boolean trueOFalse) {
        this.mensaje = mensaje;
        this.trueOFalse = trueOFalse;
    }
}
```

Y el `LiveData<Respuesta>` y en setData haces `new Respuesta(mensaje, trueOFalse)`